# Get all street, postcode, location combinations for Austria

Tags: openstreetmap

My goal is to validate an address in Austria. Without a house number, just street, postcode and city(village etc).
I have downloaded and imported austria-latest.osm.pbf from geofabrik.
My approach was  to get all postcodes, then all locations for certain postcode and at the end all roads for location. I'm using st_intersects and geometries to connect.
But i'm stuck with "Gemeinden" and can't go deeper. As example "Gemeinde Längenfeld". [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Gemeinde+L%C3%A4ngenfeld,+%C3%96sterreich/@47.0328886,10.9320658,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x479d2e2a171dffb5:0xf98b1fc1cdb9e814!8m2!3d47.07408!4d10.97106)
[Wikipedia, german](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A4ngenfeld)
You don't find "Längenfeld" as location on the address, just "Oberlängenfeld, Unterlängenfeld" and so on, but they only exists as "places" and places are just points, so i cant connect roads to them.

Do you have any hints for me? Thanks you !
P.S. we have our instance of nominatim and use it as fallback

Comment: i have taken google maps as reference, but its incorrect. The correct address is "Oberlängenfeld Nr. 1, 6444 Längenfeld", not "Oberlängenfeld Nr. 1, 6444 Oberlängenfeld" like in gmaps. So point for osm and my issue is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found perfect source for my needs. It is official "Statistik Austria". CSV-files can be found [here](https://www.statistik.at/statistik.at/strassen/#/strassenInput)

Comment: do you have a source with city -> district -> region of Austria?